# データフレームから不要な行データを削除する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

先ずはPythonで特定の行番号を取得したいです。
番号を取得後、任意の行数を抽出して、それ以降の行を削除したいです。

コードのどこがいけないのかpandasに詳しい方教えていただけませんでしょうか。

set_indexの部分でしょうか。

元のエクセル

| 国 |
| --- |
| America |
| 2022/5/10 |
| Japan |

**実現したいエクセル**
**条件**
日付がある行の番号を取得して、それ以後の行を削除したいです。
日付は毎回同じ行に表示されないです。
エクセルの中に１回のみ日付が表示されます。

| 国 |
| --- |
| America |

エラー内容

```
           国
0    America
1  2022/5/10
2      Japan

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\Documents\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    df.set_index(yesterday, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5446, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['2022/05/10'] are in the columns"
PS C:\Users\test>
```

全体のコード

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


time= dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

today= dt.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

yesterday =dt.strftime( dt.today() - relativedelta( days = 1 ), "%Y/%m/%d" )


#保存ファイル指定
file="test.csv"

#Csv読み込み
df =pd.read_csv(file)

print(df)

#set_index指定
df.set_index(yesterday, inplace=True)

#行番号取得
delete=df.index.get_loc(yesterday)
print(delete)

#2番号指定(現在手動で指定)
delete_df = df[2:]

delete_df.to_csv(file,index=False,encoding="utf_8_sig")
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)かもしれません。提示されたエクセルのCSVデータからどのような結果を得たいかを表やCSVで示してみてください。そのために必要な処理が質問記事の最初の2行になるかどうかを検討してみるのが先だと思われます。

Comment: コードを見る限り、日付をキーに該当するレコードを削除しようとしているように見えるので、タイトルや本文の "特定の行番号を取得" という説明は食い違っている印象です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問もう少し分かりやすくにします。

Comment: 質問変更致しました。もしまた何かありましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: もう少し色々な場合も考えてみましょう。最初の行が日付/複数の国名の行の後に日付/日付でも国名でもないデータはどうするか/例のように日付の後に有効な国名があっても削除するのか、といった色々な状況が発生するのかどうか・その時にどうするか(どのような結果が欲しいか)、あるいはその前に何故日付データが混ざるのかといったことも考えておいた方が良いと思われます。CSVを作る前にEXCELのマクロで対処した方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: Tracebackに `df.set_index(yesterday, inplace=True)` と出ていてそこが問題点です。
[set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) 説明読むとよいかも。なぜ `set_index()`使うのか理由が不明で, そこも質問に追記したほうがよいかも。(`set_index()`が前提にあるのか, ないのか)

Comment: みんなさん、回答ありがとうございます。
抽出条件は下記の通りです。マクロを使った方が良いでしょうか。python pandas でできないでしょうか。
日付がある行の番号を取得して、それ以後の行を削除したいです。
日付は毎回同じ行に表示されないです。
エクセルの中に１回のみ日付が表示されます。

Comment: それは使用しているEXCELファイルに不要なマクロや関数が残っているのでは？ それを探して削除した方が良いと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。任意の行番号を取得するのは難しいですね　マクロの方も試してみます。

Comment: 難しいというか直接的には出てこないだけで出来るでしょう。それよりもそうした余計なデータが入力されてしまうという状況の方が問題であって、その原因を根本的に追及して修正することが重要だと思われます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
  '国': ['America', 'Russia', '2022/5/10', 'Japan']
})
yesterday = dt.strftime( dt.today() - relativedelta( days = 1 ), "%Y/%-m/%-d" )

#
dfx = df.iloc[:m.idxmax()] if any(m:=(df['国']==yesterday)) else df
print(dfx)

#
        国
0  America
1   Russia
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法が一番シンプルで
「pandasで最大値・最小値の行名・列名を取得する」方法勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

元データが保証されていない, ようなコメントがあるので, まずはそこから …

けど, 正しいデータがあったとしても `set_index()` で何を行いたいのか未だに不明です

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import io

# テストデータ生成
dt = pd.Timestamp('2022/5')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '国': random.choices('日本 米国 英国 ドイツ フランス イタリア カナダ'.split(), k=30),
    '日付': [dt +pd.Timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 10))for _ in range(30)],
    })

with io.StringIO() as fp:
    df.to_csv(fp, index=False)
    fp.seek(0)
    # print(fp.getvalue())
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, parse_dates=[1])

yesterday = pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D') -pd.offsets.Day(1)
cnt = (df['日付'] == yesterday).sum()   # 日付に該当するデータ件数
display(df[df['日付'] == yesterday].index)   # index 一覧
```

日付項目を indexとするのなら, 以下のようにどちらかで指定
(`yesterday` という項目名は存在しない, のでは？)

```py
with io.StringIO() as fp:
    df.to_csv(fp, index=False)
    fp.seek(0)
    # print(fp.getvalue())
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, parse_dates=[1], index_col=1)   # 日付で indexとする

yesterday = pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D') -pd.offsets.Day(1)

# 日付で indexとするなら, read_csv() 時, もしくはここで指定
#df.set_index('日付', inplace=True)

lst = df.index.get_loc(yesterday)
if isinstance(lst, int):
    start = lst
    display(df[start:].head(n=3))
else:
    print(lst)
```

Comment: こちらの回答もありがとうございます。indexの指定方法について分かりました。

Answer (score 1):

何か理由があってPythonで処理したい場合には、以下の記事が参考になるでしょう。
[条件を満たす最初/最後の行を取得 - pandas](https://ikatakos.com/pot/programming/python/packages/pandas/first_row_where_true)

> ```
> # aaa列が1になる最初の行のindexを取得
> idx = df[df['aaa'] == 1].index[0]
> ```

[pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

[【Pandas】データフレームから不要な行を削除](https://pyhoo.jp/pandas-index)

> データフレームの行数を指定（０行目から２行目まで）
>
> ```
> fruits_df = fruits_df[0:3]
> ```

以下のようになります。

```
import pandas as pd
#保存ファイル指定
file="test.csv"
#Csv読み込み
df =pd.read_csv(file)
print(df)
#### ここまでは質問のソースの必要部分、以下が日付データの行以後を削除してセーブする処理

#### 日付データが存在しない場合も考えてtry exceptで囲む
try:
  idx = df[df['国'].str.match(r'\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}') == True].index[0]
  delete_df = df[:idx]
  delete_df.to_csv(file,index=False,encoding="utf_8_sig")
except:
  pass
```

Comment: 丁寧に回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法で出来ました。